# what is the best and safest way to allow users to register to site

Tags: login, user-registration

I'm wanting to allow users to register to my wordpress site. What is the best and safest way to implement this?

The ultimate goal is to give the users the option to subscribe to alerts when updates are made to the site.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to make sure you have the following settings under `Settings > General`. 
Under the **Membership**  settings make sure
`Anyone can register` is checked and `New User Default Role` is set to subscriber.

This will allow people to register at `example.com/wp-login.php?action=register` You can also use plugins like [theme my login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/) or [Gravity Forms User registration](http://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/user-registration/) (and I'm sure others) to make the sign up pages/process simpler.

I guess I'd have to know more about why you want to allow subscribers. If you wanted an even more limited role then subscibers provides you could create a new role via [role scoper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/) or the [members plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) and assign that to new users.

However, if your goal is just to give users updates why not just provide them updates via email. There are a ton of plugins that do this. Automattic has one via [jetpack](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jetpack/) or [Subscribe2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe2/) is also an easy way to do this.

Comment: As an addition to the answer, wordpress provides [RSS feeds](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds) as well